# What would be another way to write this query using union?

Tags: mysql

So i have this query joining country and region tables with the aim to display a countries capital, and regionID. Some countries don't have capitals hence the outer join. I'm trying to understand the use of the UNION clause to write this another way.

```
SELECT country, capital, RegionID  
FROM country
LEFT OUTER JOIN region ON country.CountryID = region.CountryID  
GROUP BY country;
```

Comment: `Union` is generally for when you have two queries that produce the same sets of columns, and you want to combine them together. A `join` is more appropriate when you are creating results by combining related tables. If you have information from both tables in each row, then `join` is the proper tool to use.

Comment: assuming country is unique there isn't any point to `GROUP BY country`